# Worauf ist bei der Wiedergabe von Zitaten in Texten zu achten?

Tags: quotes

Wie lauten die for­ma­len Re­geln des Zi­tie­rens?

Wie zitiert man in wört­licher bzw. in in­direk­ter Rede korrekt?

Comment: Geht es dir um die richtige Anordnung der Satzzeichen oder um die Grammatik?

Comment: Für großartigen Lesestoff diesbezüglich empfehle ich Daniel Kehlmanns *Die Vermessung der Welt* über Gauss und Alexander von Humboldt. Das Buch ist quasi vollständig in indirekter Rede verfasst.

Comment: Das kommt darauf an. Hier an der Uni hat jeder Fachbereich seinen eigenen Zitierstil.

Comment: @thei sowohl als auch. Es gibt sicher einige Dinge, die ich beachten muss, wenn ich richtig zitieren möchte: Anführungszeichen, Verwendung des Konjunktivs...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Wörtliches Zitat

Ein wörtliches Zitat muss wirklich wörtlich sein, also es „[…] muss formal und inhaltlich völlig mit dem Original, auch Hervorhebungen […] und eigenwillige Zeichensetzung, übereinstimmen.“ ([Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zitat#W.C3.B6rtliches_Zitat)) Wie in anderen Sprachen auch, muss es in Anführungszeichen gesetzt werden, kann dabei sowohl direkt in den Satz integriert werden, oder aber getrennt (beispielsweise nach Doppelpunkt) genannt werden. Wikipedia schreibt außerdem: „Eigene Hervorhebungen oder eingeschobene Erläuterungen – in eckigen Klammern – müssen durch einen Hinweis […] herausgestellt werden.”

Ist ein längeres wörtliches Zitat vorgesehen, so schreibt man diese als eigenständige Paragraphen und rückt diesen ein (vgl. die Zitatfunktion hier von Markdown).

#### Sinngemäßes Zitat

Beim sinngemäßen Zitat ist lediglich der Inhalt wichtig. Syntaktische Vorgaben, wie die Verwendung von Anführungszeichen, fallen komplett weg. Stattdessen kann man frei den Sinn wiedergeben. Dabei würde ich immer unterscheiden, ob der Inhalt wirklich fakt ist, oder es nur eine Aussage des Autors, von dem das Zitat stammt, ist. Im letzteren Fall sollte man dann den Konjunktiv verwenden.

#### Quellenangaben

Viel wichtiger als das korrekte Zitieren ist eigentlich die Quellenangabe. Dabei ist es stark davon abhängig, wo dein Text veröffentlicht wird. Beispielsweise gibt es an Unis immer feste Regeln, *wie* Quellenangaben geschrieben werden, und auch wo solche Angaben auftauchen (also direkt nach dem Zitat, oder beispielsweise in einer Fußzeile).

Ist es nicht unbedingt ein wissenschaftlicher Text, dann kannst du die Quellenangaben eigentlich so schreiben, wie du es für richtig hältst. Wichtig ist vor allem, dass Autor, evtl. Titel und Veröffentlichungsjahr angegeben sind.